# Pandas - Concatenate values of lists into a single column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate a list of nth entries into a single column in a pandas-data frame.

The number of entries of the list can variate.

Sample Input:

```
a = {"unix_group_A": [
      "abc4034",
      "abc7228",
      "abc7231",
      "abc7230",
      "abc3555",
      "abc7216"
   ],
   "unix_group_B": [
      "asdfasd4034",
      "asdfasd7228",
      "asdfasd7231",
      "asdfasd7230",
      "asdfasd3555",
      "asdfasd7216",
       "asdf"
   ]}
```

Output of:

```py
df_bla = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
[enter image description here][1]
```

Expected Output:

```
0               1       
unix_group_A  abc4034, abc7228, abc7231, abc7230, abc3555, abc7216
unix_group_B  asdfasd4034, asdfasd7228, asdfasd7231, asdfasd7230, asdfasd3555, asdfasd7216, asdf
```

I couldn't find a question which fits my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
pd.DataFrame([[k, ", ".join(v)] for k, v in a.items()])
```

---

```
              0                                                  1
0  unix_group_A  abc4034, abc7228, abc7231, abc7230, abc3555, a...
1  unix_group_B  asdfasd4034, asdfasd7228, asdfasd7231, asdfasd...
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
But how do I get the result when I read the dataframe from a JSON?
With pd.read_json(filepath)

Sorry for the additional question.